# Find the value of $a$ so that $PM+PN$ is minimized.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

> Let $M=(1,3), N=(-1,1)$ and $P=(a,2a)$ be three points. Find the value of $a$ so that $PM+PN$ is minimized.

What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min+f(a)%3Dsqrt%7B(a-1)%5E2%2B(2a-3)%5E2%7D%2Bsqrt%7B(a%2B1)%5E2%2B(2a-1)%5E2%7D

Comment: There are several ways to solve this. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflect $M$ across the line $y=2x$ and you get the point $M'$. Then $$(PM+PN)_{\min } = M'N$$
and $P$ is the point where line $M'N$ cuts line $y=2x$.

Quick draw in geogebra gives $a=1.1$.

Comment: Has the OP understood that $P$ moves along this line ?

Comment: Ask him.........

Comment: @John Watson , Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Yes, calculate the minimum of the function $$f(a)=\sqrt{(a-1)^2+(2a-3)^2}+\sqrt{(a+1)^2+(2a-1)^2}$$

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420497/the-value-of-k-that-makes-overlineac-overlinebc-as-small-as-possible/2420503#2420503

Answer (score 3):

The perpendicular line to $y=2x$ and passing through $N(-1,1)$: $y=-\frac12x+\frac12$.

The intersection point of the two lines: $(\frac15;\frac25)$.

The reflection point $N'$ of the point $N$ over the line $y=2x$: $(\frac75;-\frac15)$.

The line $MN'$: $y=-8x+11$.

The intersection point of the lines $y=-8x+11$ and $y=2x$: $(\frac{11}{10};\frac{22}{10})$. Hence: $a=\frac{11}{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

By Minkowski (the triangle inequality) we obtain:
$$PM+PN=\sqrt{(a-1)^2+(2a-3)^2}+\sqrt{(a+1)^2+(2a-1)^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{5a^2-14a+10}+\sqrt{5a^2-2a+2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\sqrt{25a^2-70a+50}+\sqrt{25a^2-10a+10}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\sqrt{(5a-7)^2+1^2}+\sqrt{(1-5a)^2+3^2}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\sqrt{(5a-7+1-5a)^2+(1+3)^2}=2\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}.$$
The equality occurs when $$(5a-7,1)||(1-5a,3),$$ which gives
$$\frac{5a-7}{1-5a}=\frac{1}{3}$$ or $a=1.1$, which says that $2\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}$ is a minimal value.

Done!

Comment: No, it suffices to draw a figure to see that choosing $P$ at the intersection of line MN and line with equation $y=2x$ does not provide the minimum.

Comment: @Jean Marie I fixed my post. See now.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe @John Watson's answer is more elegant. But just for fun, I'm going to do the "brute force" method, which is to minimize the distance function

$$ \begin{align} f(a) &= \sqrt{(a-1)^2 + (2a-3)^2} + \sqrt{(a+1)^2 + (2a-1)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{5a^2-14a+10} + \sqrt{5a^2-2a+2} 
\end{align} $$

Then

$$ f'(a) = \frac{5a-7}{\sqrt{5a^2-14a+10}} + \frac{5a-1}{\sqrt{5a^2-2a+2}} $$

Solving $f'(a) = 0$ leads to the equation
$$ (5a-7)\sqrt{5a^2-2a+2} + (5a-1)\sqrt{5a^2-14a+10} = 0 $$

From here we impose the condition

$$ \frac{5a-1}{5a-7} = -\sqrt{\frac{5a^2-2a+2}{5a^2-14a+10}} < 0 $$

or $$ \frac{1}{5} < a < \frac{7}{5} \tag{1} $$

Next, rewrite the question as
$$ (5a-7)\sqrt{(5a-1)^2+9} + (5a-1)\sqrt{(5a-7)^2+1} = 0 $$

Rearranging terms and squaring both sides we end up with
$$ 9(5a-7)^2 = (5a-1)^2 $$

This gives two solutions $a = 2$ and $a = \frac{11}{10}$, but only the latter satisifes $(1)$

Therefore the answer is $a = 1.1$